# TextField space between Label and Text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I need to give a spacing of 4.dp between Label and Text in my TextField using Compose. I use a small font size and input text seems misaligned. I need the Text shown down. rewards and thank you for help.

Current Preview

[image: current]

My Code

[image: code]

Comment: Hi, Markdown syntax supports code support ([link](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#code)). It would be a lot better if you could add this image as `code`.

Answer (score 0):

use modifier in for the label

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextField() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        label = {
            Text(
                text = "Label",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 4.dp)
            )
        },
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 12.sp // or whatever small size you're using
        ),
        singleLine = true
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried but apparently the textfield doesn't apply well and the padding overlaps the text.